# What is the optimal hardware setup for a server designed to produce blocks with EOSIO?

Tags: block-producer

When setting up a block producer server, what is the optimal hardware in order to produce blocks, where the criteria is:

1. CPU speed must be as fast as possible at producing blocks
2. Number of cores is basically irrelevant, as only 1 core can be used for block production anyway
3. Read/Write speed to disk should be as fast as possible and allow for huge data storage (assuming the block producer is storing full history and wants to provide quick access to it)

How should the hardware be configured in order to maximise efficiency?